# Is it safe to overclock laptop monitor?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, dell-inspiron, refresh-rate

I was watching a pro gamer today and he mentioned that he's using a new screen resolution. I decided to give it a try to test if it looks good and offers a considerable lower input delay.

I launched the "Intel Graphics Settings" and I navigated to "Display". I clicked on the resolution window and tried to find the resolution I wanted to use but it wasn't there.

On the left, I noticed "Custom Resolutions" so I clicked on it and the following message appeared:

> Warning: Altering resolutions may 1. Reduce system stability and useful life of the system and chipset; 2. Cause the chipset and other system components to fail; etc... Do you want to continue?

I hit "Yes" and I was surprised that there was a window to set custom refresh rate for the monitor! I had no idea my laptop pc allows me to overclock my monitor. It's a 60hz monitor and the non-custom available options were: 48hz & 60hz only.

Do you guys think it's safe to up the refresh rate to something like 144hz?
If 144hz is too high, what value is acceptable?

Comment: It is almost certain that the monitor will simply not display any image at all at 144Hz. Likely the electronics will be incapable of accepting a signal sent that fast. What your monitor might accept can only be found out by trial and error but likely the defaults chosen by the manufacturer are near the maximum the panel supports. After all they would hardly use an expensive 144Hz capable panel in a cheap 60Hz monitor, it would be a waste of money on their part and would cut into their profits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a resolution & refresh rate it was capable of, but probably doesn't look good so the manufacturer sensibly didn't include it in the options. If you set it to something it **can't** do, then you're far more likely to end up with a black screen you can't escape from without some serious behind-the-scenes digging through the registry or BIOS.

No-one is going to put a 144Hz screen in a computer & hide it from the user. It just makes absolutely no business/marketing sense whatsoever.

Heed the warning.

Comment: Would this even be possible for flatscreens of any kind? Old CRTs would accept different refresh rates and actually be able to display them as such (assuming the resolution desired was capable of it on that monitor), but for TFTs it's mostly just 60Hz, 120Hz. for a few models. Unless their claims are supported by actual hardware pro's I wouldn't go with pro gamer recommendations anyway, for reasons of product placement and downright superstition.

Comment: @MiG even CRTs were limited by how fast the beam could be pulled across the screen in the horizontal and vertical directions and that depended largely on how the electronics was set up and how quickly it could "read" the incoming signals. Modern screens are just more precisely limited due to the increased amount of electronics in both the output display stage as well as the input stages. All electronics has what is known as a "slew rate" as in how fast a signal can go from 0 to 1 and hack again and digital electronics it is even more important because you need sharp transitions.

Comment: I'm aware, with CRTs, higher resolutions would mean lower refresh rates, scanning beam could only go so fast. Was just trying to illustrate that a long time ago this mattered, probably the kernel of obsolescent truth at the heart of this. Not so anymore though.